# Does Hashmap use random access?

Tags: java, hashmap

In HashMap in java,I understood that **hash values are stored in buckets** which helps in faster searching.
 While retrieving, It checks for the hashcode and accordingly finds the bucket number. 
If there are bucket number from 1 to 10 and the bucket number found from hash code is bucket number 5
.
 **How do the control transferred to bucket number 5? Does it traverse through bucket 1 to bucket 4 and reach 5 or does it uses any other mechanism?**

Comment: You should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashmap...

Comment: ... or any good textbook on data structures.

Comment: You should mark homework as such.

Comment: ... or read the source code for HashMap which says how it works. (It in your JDK and your IDE can find it for you)

Comment: @Viruzzo: I can't imagine a teacher asking how "control is transferred" to a bucket in a hashtable.

Comment: @all Three users gave me answer for this question so I guess My question was not that bad. And those who felt it was simple question then you guys should have answered and then commented on it. Jobless people

Comment: Find src.zip in the jdk installation directory. Find file java.util.HashMap.java and learn it.

Comment: I think those people who answered for this are then people who are worthy to be a user at this site. Others should be banned

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov Thanks for that!!!

Comment: @suraj: No one has suggested that your question is "bad" or "simple".  But for your subsequent obnoxious attitude, you've earned yourself -1 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hash table is implemented as an array of buckets, so it uses the array's [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) indexing to get to the right bucket given the hash.

Answer (score 6):

It's direct array access. No iteration/traversal. But then it must traverse the objects **inside** the bucket and compare with `equals`. Maybe that's confusing you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hash Function is used to locate the bucket.**

If there are 10 buckets, let's for example say that for a set of strings, the character values are added and hashed to 10 buckets

Let's write a trivial hash function to map strings into 10 buckets,

```
 For any non empty String, 

             hash function f = sum of (index of characters) % 10
```

example  : abc  = 1+2+3 %10   = 6. So "abc" ends up in the 6th bucket.
            xyz = 24+25+25 %10  = 7.5~ 8 . So "xyz" ends up in the 8th bucket and so on

So when you serach for "xyz" , the hash function directly finds the bucket here.

A [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is at the heart of working of hash map.

Answer (score 2):

Excerpt from java.util.HashMap code

```
         /**
          * Adds a new entry with the specified key, value and hash code to
          * the specified bucket.  It is the responsibility of this
          * method to resize the table if appropriate.
          *
          * Subclass overrides this to alter the behavior of put method.
          */
         void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
             Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
             table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
             if (size++ >= threshold)
                 resize(2 * table.length);
         }
```

So it's accessed randomly from an Array.

Answer (score 0):

There are several strategies while adding and retrieving the values some of them are direct chaning, open addressing etc
Based on these the way it stores and fetching values will change.For example, in direct chaining each space of bucket
array is pointer to a linked list that contains the key-value pairs that hashed to the same location.So when you search the value, it is scanning the entire list with the give value.